# Kivy: keeping draw instructions in view, while view scrolls

Tags: python, user-interface, scrollview, kivy

As the topic title states, I want to keep some GUI draw instructions in view while the screen scrolls (using canvas).  I'm using the only kivy api call that allows you to do so....

```
               def GetWCords(self, x=0, y=0):
                return self.GW.to_widget(x, y, False)
```

### self.GW = Game World

### x, y default to zero because I want the bottom left corner of where the view starts.

The problem is, the GUI offsets when the screen scroll as if the "to_widget" call is not returning for the next frame (lag, slow, etc).

Does anyone know of a better way or fix for having still GUI draw instructions stay in view while the view scrolls?